# Recover comand is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to use recover command to recover my deleted file, however when I use it, process got aborted with below error:
**recover: No valid standard devices found; are you a privileged user?**

Please find below screen-shot for the same:
[image]

Below are my system Details:
OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Please post text as text. And can you show output of `findmnt`.

Comment: To add text to this post, replacing the picture, run it again, select and copy all the text to paste, then click [edit] and you're back in the original question, where you can remove the picture and paste in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I think recover can only be used on ext2 formatted disks.   Please check if the file you're trying to recover is on this type - fdisk -l  will display attached disks.  Also if the file system is still mounted r/w there's a chance the deleted file has been over written.